# ERC20- Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted] Transfer Already Created Token

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, remix, myetherwallet

I have created contract on Ropston TestNet which will send any already created tokens.

Unfortunately its giving me error

Transaction Details Available at: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x573387d8f0d24c090f9314bc6429040d415b119eb2850ec042b7d31e6a8cabe1

Contract Code: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x268359be8042358adc2fc9f72fe3d4132ed2015d#code

Note: I am calling function transfer which accept 3 parameters including (TokenContractAdreess, Receiver Address and Value). Contract has 2 functions with same name.

Please help me where I am lacking.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

The function you are invoking does this

```
function transfer(address tokenAddress, address dests, uint256 values) public
{
        ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(dests, values);
}
```

The inner transfer is failing.

One likely cause is your contract doesn't have balance. You are transfering from your contract to recipient, not from the sender.